# Ошибка вебпака при начальной сборке, но стабильная работа в hot-reload?

Tags: vue.js, typescript, webpack

Есть объемный проект на Vue, написанный частично на TS, частично на JS. В нем все стабильно работает, постепенно переходим полностью на TS, но суть не в этом.
Делаю виджет одной из страниц этого проекта. Встраивается скрипт, инициализируется Vue приложение. В основном компоненте только внешняя верстка и функционал, а более мелкие (глупые) компоненты импортируются напрямую из файлов проекта (так как виджет разворачивается параллельно с основным проектом, но не суть). Некоторые компоненты импортируются через index.ts:

```
import ButtonCanRequest from '@/presets/button/can-request';
```

А некоторые - напрямую файлом (то есть обычным JS):

```
import ExtLink from '@/components/ext/Link.vue';
```

Так вот, к проблеме. При сборке виджета выдает сотни ошибок такого формата - **ругается только на файлы с расширением *.vue** (к слову, файл Datepicker.vue в виджете не импортируется и не используется):

```
Module build failed: Error: Could not find file: '[project]\src\components\form\Datepicker.vue'.
at getValidSourceFile ([project]\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:114896:23)
at Object.getEmitOutput ([project]\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:115259:30)
at Object.getEmitOutput ([project]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\instances.js:155:41)
at getEmit ([project]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:172:35)
at successLoader ([project]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:42:11)
at Object.loader ([project]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:29:12)
```

Самое интересное, что если убрать все компоненты из верстки, закомментить импорты, сборка пройдет нормально. А затем **вернуть все импорты** и верстку на место - сработает hot-reload и все заработает без ошибок! Третий час я бьюсь с этой проблемой. Пробовал обновлять модули, лоадеры, немного менял конфигурацию вебпака, все бесполезно. Куда копать, может кто сталкивался?

Конфиг Webpack:

```js
    var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    catalog: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/catalog.js'),
    detail: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/detail.js'),
    activity: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/activity.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: `/dist/widgets/`,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'elysium-common': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      '~@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(isProd ? {
      analyzerMode: 'disabled',
      reportFilename: 'report.html',
      generateStatsFile: true,
      statsFilename: 'stats.json',
      logLevel: 'silent'
    } : {
        // Can be `server`, `static` or `disabled`.
        // In `server` mode analyzer will start HTTP server to show bundle report.
        // In `static` mode single HTML file with bundle report will be generated.
        // In `disabled` mode you can use this plugin to just generate Webpack Stats JSON file by setting `generateStatsFile` to `true`.
        analyzerMode: 'disabled',
        // Host that will be used in `server` mode to start HTTP server.
        analyzerHost: '127.0.0.1',
        // Port that will be used in `server` mode to start HTTP server.
        analyzerPort: 8888,
        // Path to bundle report file that will be generated in `static` mode.
        // Relative to bundles output directory.
        reportFilename: 'report.html',
        // Module sizes to show in report by default.
        // Should be one of `stat`, `parsed` or `gzip`.
        // See "Definitions" section for more information.
        defaultSizes: 'parsed',
        // Automatically open report in default browser
        openAnalyzer: true,
        // If `true`, Webpack Stats JSON file will be generated in bundles output directory
        generateStatsFile: false,
        // Name of Webpack Stats JSON file that will be generated if `generateStatsFile` is `true`.
        // Relative to bundles output directory.
        statsFilename: 'stats.json',
        // Options for `stats.toJson()` method.
        // For example you can exclude sources of your modules from stats file with `source: false` option.
        // See more options here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/webpack-1/lib/Stats.js#L21
        statsOptions: null,
        // Log level. Can be 'info', 'warn', 'error' or 'silent'.
        logLevel: 'info'
    }),
  ]
}

if (isProd) {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: Самое время выложить webpack.config.
Меня, например, смущает вот это `Could not find file: '[project]\src\components\form\Datepicker.vue`

Это разве валидный путь ?

Comment: Путь я заменил, там просто слишком длинная строка пути. Сам файл по этому пути существует. Конфиг выложил в вопрос

Comment: Меня немного смущают алиасы, честно говоря, корректно ли они прописаны, но ничего конкретного не могу сказать, у меня проблем таких не возникает, у меня везде импорт относительными путями сделан.

Comment: Алиасы нормально работают, как минимум потому, что остальные компоненты (которые импортируются без расширения .vue) вполне стабильно работают.

Comment: А нет зависимости что не находит файлы где  lang="ts" указан, например ? 
Я тут на просторах нашел похожую проблему https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/263#issuecomment-294482203
помимо прочего говорят проверить в  `tsconfig ` `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,`

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, добавление этого в конфиг проблемы не решило. В данный момент решил так - скопировал компоненты в папку виджета и переписал на js. Но все равно это не есть хорошо